# C# VS2010 Express: Program runs in IDE, but not as exe, why?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010

I have worked on this for two days.   My code I have worked on for 6 months.

My program, tested with all the exceptions turned on.  No errors. I can hook up to the control hardware... and it communicates, runs, is a GUI for a new CNC system I am building.

Works perfect, with hundreds of features, as needed.  I have built and tested always with the hardware all along.  Always testing in the IDE.

Now I am ready to create the ".exe" file and run... No go... what???  You mean it works flawlessly in the IDE and when that IDE creates the exe, it don't?  I am frustrated.

I have read and read, and try many things... but what bugs me the most.  Is it works perfect in the IDE but not outside of it.

A lot of the reccomendations are with tools I don't have.  I have the express version.

When in the IDE it runs in debug and without debug.
Go external, and try to run the exe without the IDE, no go.  Never even starts at all.
Why?

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

I try to run by going to the bin/release or bin/debug, externally.  Double click the .exe.
I have also installed and it also does the same thing. Don't run.
The event info. also shows this info. below.

---

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: truemachinecnc4.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 53bf29fb
  Problem Signature 04: KMotion_dotNet
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.1.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5133ac38
  Problem Signature 07: 3a
  Problem Signature 08: e1
  Problem Signature 09: KMotion_dotNet.DMException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: If you don't even know if your code is C# or C++ (due to mixed tags) how do you expect one to provide you good recommendation?

Comment: All my code is C#... and to access the software related to the hardware, I have one .net .dll that gives me the access to all the hardwares code which is mostly C++ and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to execute the program, outside of the IDE?  If you are copying the file to a new location, it's possible there are dependencies on other DLLs which need to be copied along with it.

Check the Windows Event Log.  It should have exception information when your program fails to launch.  Include those details in your description.

Comment: I have added this info. above... I go to the bin/release or bin/debug, as well install and try to run.  All give the same error.

Comment: Problem was related to folder location, and dependencies, of another program I did not write.  Once in the folder, that held all the dlls it finally worked.